# How can I skip a github url from periodic that does not exist anymore?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, goland

GitToolBox plugin in Intellij and GoLand give me this error each time they fetch. Apparently, the error is correct. The issue is that the repository does not exist. How can I set GitToolbox plugin to skip this url from fetch (change .git/config to skip the fetch?)

This is the error I get:

```
3:11 PM Auto fetch failed in src/github.com/blendlabs/go-exception
                src/github.com/blendlabs/go-exception: remote: Repository not found.
                Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/blendlabs/go-exception/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether there is such an option for GitToolBox.

You can use IntelliJ VCS integration and use **"Pull" action** as a workaround since it allows you to choose a remote to pull from.

There are a few **feature requests** regarding Fetch (please vote):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89709

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24057

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100846

and **known issue** reported:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158958